# Problem with Installing Debian - How to format disk with Start CD

Tags: debian, system-installation

I am thrilled to try and install Debian 10 on my Thinkpad 7th gen.
I was able to install it, but had to redo the installation because of missing firmware drivers.
Anyway, the next installation went wrong, for whatever reason. (I was getting a "volume group debian not found" error).
Now during another reinstall attempt, I realise that I have created a huge partion mess. I have more than 6 partitions?
How can I delete them?
How can I just format the whole disk and start with a clean install. I used the following guide https://wiki.debian.org/SetupGuides/SecurePersonalComputer, and it also recommends a format before install.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! To avoid installing firmware you can use the [non-free isos](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.5.0-live+nonfree/). You can wipe the disk by using gparted, wich you can install in the live session of Debian.

Comment: thank you I am downloading the live iso and will try.

Comment: I could wipe the drive but and the bios only shows the boot menu, nothing else anymore.
I might have to flash a new bios first?

Comment: *I could wipe the drive but and the bios only shows the boot menu*. I'm not sure I understand... if you wiped the drive then nothing will boot except your debian installation USB... or I'm missing something?

Comment: sorry I was just able to "find" bios again so I guess no need to flash a new one. Sorry I am still learning,. will try to install the non free version now on the wiped drive.

Comment: Ok! Report back if you have problems.

Comment: unfortunately, despite having wiped the drive, the partition menu again looks like this (screenshot: https://ibb.co/rG2GdNG) is this supposed to look like that?
In any case, the installation does not work from there on. it says, The failing step is: Install the system

Comment: Then you didn't wipe the disk... you have to use gparted to delete the partitions and create new ones.